# ESRI tile service not loading correctly in web maps

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openlayers-3

I tried to use the example from openlayers 3 xyz example to create a webmap from this  service http://maps.gov.bc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/Province/web_mercator_cache/MapServer but the map rendered is not complete.  It is better with the wrapX: false but the issue is not resolved.  It also fails to display correctly using Leaflet.

Here is JS fiddle with the OL3 code.

http://jsfiddle.net/7ettuy1c/

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: "http://maps.gov.bc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/Province/web_mercator_cache/MapServer" +
            '/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-118, 51.5]),
    zoom: 1
  })
});
```

Comment: The map looks fine to me when the source is configured with 'wrapX: false'. What exactly is the issue you're seeing?

Comment: The map loads but only about 1/4 of the area that should be shown is there.   This is what it should look like -  http://maps.gov.bc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/Province/web_mercator_cache/MapServer?f=jsapi

Comment: This is the leaflet snip   

var map = L.map('map').setView([55.5, -121.691067], 5);  L.tileLayer('http://maps.gov.bc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/province/web_mercator_cache/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
 attribution: 'Province of British Columbia'
 }).addTo(map);